# How can I configure Automatic Memory Management for certain target values?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, memory, parameter

I am a little confused about the Oracle Database configuration.

**My server:**

- Operating system: Windows Server 2012 R2 64bit
- RAM: 40GB
- Oracle: Oracle Database 12c (12.1.0.2.0) 64bit

**My aim:**

- Oracle should use 32GB of 40GB RAM
- AMM should be activated (I don't want to configure everything myself)

**The current parameters:**

```
SQL> SHOW PARAMETER SGA
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------
lock_sga                             boolean     FALSE
pre_page_sga                         boolean     TRUE
sga_max_size                         big integer 20G
sga_target                           big integer 0


SQL> SHOW PARAMETER PGA
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------
pga_aggregate_limit                  big integer 9827M
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 8G


SQL> SHOW PARAMETER MEMORY
NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ---------
memory_max_target                    big integer 32G
memory_target                        big integer 32G
```

1. Should I set `sga_max_size` and `pga_aggregate_target` to zero?
2. Is everything else configured correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set `SGA_MAX_SIZE` parameter when using AMM.
It fixes the SGA size.

If you set `pga_aggregate_target` to non-zero value when using AMM, then you set a lower bound for PGA size. This is usually not required.

Parameter `pga_aggregate_limit` sets upper PGA bound. For the start, leave it to default value.

Answer (score 2):

*Oracle® Database, Administrator’s Guide, 12c Release 1 (12.1)* describes this

[Enabling Automatic Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/memory.htm#ADMIN11200)

> With MEMORY_TARGET set, the SGA_TARGET setting becomes the minimum size of the SGA and the PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET setting becomes the minimum size of the instance PGA. By setting both of these to zero as shown, there are no minimums, and the SGA and instance PGA can grow as needed as long as their sum is less than or equal to the MEMORY_TARGET setting. The sizing of SQL work areas remains automatic.
>
> You can omit the statements that set the SGA_TARGET and PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET parameter values to zero and leave either or both of the values as positive numbers. In this case, the values act as minimum values for the sizes of the SGA or instance PGA.
>
> In addition, you can use the PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT initialization parameter to set an instance-wide hard limit for PGA memory. You can set PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT whether or not you use automatic memory management. See "[Using Automatic PGA Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/memory.htm#GUID-2B2581E8-DFD7-4FA0-9C2A-86E485235B78)".